# Does the homotopy category of a model category detect weak equivalences?

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a model category. Suppose that a morphism $f:x\to y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ induces an isomorphism in the homotopy category $\textbf{Ho}(\mathcal{C})$. Is it necessarily true that $f$ is a weak equivalence in $\mathcal{C}$?

If not, are there nice sufficient conditions for this to hold? For instance, does it hold for simplicial model categories?

Comment: This is Theorem 8.3.10 in Hirschhorn's book.

Comment: @GregoryArone thank you!

Comment: Maybe this should be called "the fundamental theorem of model categories" or something.

Comment: In Quillen's original definition of model category this was not necessarily the case. The model categories with this property were referred to as *closed* model categories, a term that I have seen in use here and tehre until perhaps a decade ago.